# Asp.net https allow only payment page

Tags: c#, asp.net, https

I know some asp.net http block techniques. I have payment page `Payment.aspx`. I want to apply https only this page other pages will use http but `Payment.aspx` will use https.

```
    pageName = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
    if (pageName == "http://?????.com/Payment.aspx")
    {
        Response.Redirect("https://?.com/Payment.aspx");
    }
```

This tehniques do not work because of my server provider. Waiting your suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(!Request.IsSecureConnection)
{
    //perform your redirect here.
}
```

Use the Request.IsSecureConnection to detect if HTTPS is being used. Don't try to recognize magic strings.

Comment: I added this code but    
`if (!Request.IsSecureConnection)
{
    Label1.Text = "Not Secure";

}
else 
{
    Label1.Text = "SSL CARE";
}`
When i enter https page write not secure. My ssl not working or this code wrong place added in page load ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do some SSL change for it you can use the mentioned link for it

[Click here](http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2005/08/17/163100.aspx)

Comment: i have a ssl when i enter url with https `https://sophsis.com/OdemeYap.aspx`, I can enter but if i enter url like this `http://sophsis.com/OdemeYap.aspx` again i can join without ssl. I want to block http only this page